# No results (blank) upon running the Query - trying to result from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, ansi-sql

I have the following MYSQL Query - trying to join 3 tables and find unique(Distinct)information(data)

```
SELECT a.LocationID, a.Model, a.SerialNum,a.Purpose, b.IP, a.Services,a.DeviceID, COUNT(a.Hostname)
FROM RefConnection.Equipment_Info a, RefConnection.Connections b, RefConnection.VM_Info c
JOIN Equipment_Info on b.Hostname = a.Hostname
WHERE a.Hostname = c.Hostname
  AND b.status = a.Status
  AND a.status = c.Status
GROUP BY a.LocationID, a.Model, a.SerialNum, a.Purpose, b.IP, a.Services, a.DeviceID
ORDER BY COUNT(b.Hostname)DESC;
```

This works with 2 tables :

```
SELECT d.locationID, d.Model, d.SerialNum, d.Status, da.IP, COUNT(d.HOSTNAME)
FROM RefConnection.Equipment_Info d, RefConnection.Connections da
WHERE d.Hostname = da.Hostname
  AND d.Status = da.Status
Group By d.locationID, d.Model, d.locationID, d.Model, d.SerialNum, d.Status, da.IP
ORDER BY COUNT(da.Hostname) DESC;
```

Unknown column 'b.Hostname' in 'on clause'

```
Select b.LocationID, b.Model, b.SerialNum, a.Purpose, a.IP, b.Services,b.DeviceID,c.applications,c.OS, Count(a.Hostname)
FROM RefConnection.Equipment_Info b JOIN
 RefConnection.Connections a
     ON a.Hostname = b.Hostname AND
    a.status = b.Status JOIN
 RefConnection.VM_Info c
     ON b.Hostname = c.Hostname AND
    b.status = c.Status
group by b.LocationID, b.Model, b.SerialNum, a.Purpose, a.IP, b.Services, b.DeviceID, c.applications, c.OS
order by COUNT(b.Hostname)desc;
```

Running this Query - expecting a to show the output from joining all 3 tables from the RefConnection, as in all 3 tables( Connections, Equipment_info, VM_Info) contains ( Hostname, Status). 
(Equipment_Info and VM_Info) table contains (LocationID, OS). Trying to get unique(distinct) hostnames and its status that should be linked with location ID and respective OS information. Not sure where I went wrong?

Comment: How is this related to Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

The old school comma syntax for join operation is logically equivalent to the newer `JOIN` keyword. But there's a difference in the order of precedence.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

excerpt:

> `INNER JOIN` and `,` (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table is joined to each and every row in the second table).
>
> However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than that of `INNER JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, and so on. If you **mix comma joins with the other join types** when there is a join condition, an error of the form `Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause'` may occur. Information about dealing with this problem is given later in this section.

---

Best practice is to NOT mix comma syntax and JOIN syntax in the same statement.

Best practice for new SQL is to just avoid the comma syntax. It's great that support is there for legacy SQL. But new SQL doesn't need to use it.

Comment: the question refers to the 3rd code block - in which comma is avoided.

Comment: We would not expect the third SQL statement to throw error **`Unknown column 'b.Hostname' in 'on clause'`** (That's the error shown in the body of the question.) We are assuming `hostname` is a valid reference to a column in `RefConnection.Equipment_Info` (successful completion of the second SQL statement is evidence of that). And that's the first table/view referenced in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: If the question is not about the first SQL statement, then why does the question include that SQL statement along with the expected error message (Unknown column 'b.Hostname' in 'on clause')?  It's not at all clear what question is being asked.

Comment: I did post it as a new question not sure why it picked the previous question which was resolved. Is it possible for you to look at the last SQL Code and why its not showing any results?  I am kind a lost here.